# Fast CRC of a Drawing.Bitmap

Tags: c#, caching, bitmap, crc

On application startup I build a cache of icons (24x24 32bbp pre-multiplied argb bitmaps). this cache contains roughly a thousand items. I don't want to store the same image multiple times in this cache, for both memory and performance reasons. I figured the best way would be to create some sort of crc from each bitmap as it goes into the cache, and to compare new bitmaps against this list of crcs.

What is a good (and fast) way to create a crc from a bitmap which is only loaded in memory?

Or am I totally on the wrong track and is there a better way to build a bitmap-cache?

Comment: What identifier do you use to retrieve the images from the cache?

Comment: At the moment I'm returning an index into the image array. The caching and duplicate-testing should all happen behind the scenes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While I would echo what Hans has said, I believe that you can do this but CRC is a bad algorithm to use.

You can instead create an MD5 hash of the bytes of the generated bitmap.  By my calculations your images must be a minimum of 2Kb in size.  To generate a hash you can either calculate it across the whole bitmap, or you can be sneaky and do it on every *n* th byte - which would be faster on the hash side but probably heavier on memory usage as you'll have to extract those bytes into a new array.

If you were going to skip every nth byte, I would use 4 or 2 - using 4 means you read one component from each consecutive pixel, using two means you read two components from each consecutive pixel.

However, MD5 is *very* fast and you might find (and I would benchmark this in a unit test) that just hashing across the whole bitmap will be faster.

***The only thing is***, I can't see how you can check in advance whether you *should* generate a given bitmap without in advance knowing it's hash and the only way you can know it's hash is to generate it.  In which case by that point you might as well just save the new image out.  An extra element in your image cache array isn't going to break the universe.

What you really need to be able to do here to actually save space and startup time is to know in advance of generating an image whether it's going to be the same as another.  Given that these images are generated dynamically is it the case that, when two identical images are generated, they are generated by the same method call with the same parameters?

If so, you could instead look at tagging each generated image with one or more hashcodes (using `object.GetHashCode()`) for the `MethodInfo` of the method that generates the image (you can get that inside the method itself by calling `MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod()`, along with each hashcode for each parameter that was passed in.  The hashcode for the method is quite reliable, as it uses the runtime's method handle (which is unique for each method) - the only hash code compression that can occur there is on 64 bit machines where the handle is 64 bit, but the hash code is 32.  However, in practise such a collision rarely occurs since you'd have to have a huge amount of code in the application to cause the first 32 bits of two separate method handles to bee the same.

The hash codes of the individual parameters, of course, are far less reliable unless those parameter types have good hash code functions.

This solution would by no means be perfect (at worst you'd still get some duplicates), but I reckon it would speed things up.  Like I say, though, it relies on your duplicated images always being generated by the same calls.

Comment: Andras, thank you so much for the extensive answer. I've implemented an MD5 hash of the bitmap bytes and initial tests are good. No false positives, no false negatives. The image cache contains about 500 entries now (more in the future), but the number of instances in my app that use these icons numbers easily into the thousands. That is the overhead I'm hoping to get rid of.

Comment: @David Rutten: Glad to be of help.  It's an interesting challenge (and I'm sure there are other ways, but I think this is probably the best 'easy' solution).  I had a similar issue with storing XML of 7k + in a DB but not wishing to store dupes.  I used MD5 hashing for that and never got a collision.

Answer (score 1):

A CRC has the same flaw as any hashing function: an equal CRC value does *not* proof that the images are identical.  Your program will randomly, but infrequently, display the wrong image.

You need something else.  Like the filename from which you retrieved the bitmap.

Comment: Hi Hans, images typically come from resources, or might even be created on the spot using drawing functions. There is no filename.